# Magnify a portion of image on canvas

Tags: android

How do I magnify the clicked portion of image using canvas. I tried to use the idea of cropping, but found that cropping use  built-in system

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BitmapRegionDecoder` to get the area of the Image you want to magnify and display it in a separate view.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
yourImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

byte[] bmpArray = stream.toByteArray();
BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(bmpArray, 0, bmpArray.length, false);
Bitmap region = decoder.decodeRegion(new Rect(leftCoordinate, topCoordinate, rightCoordinate, bottomCoordinate), null);
```

This might solve your issue